# How can I solve that gradle error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

```
Asset manifest contains a null or empty uri.
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-2.2.11\android\src\main\java\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast\fluttertoast\FluttertoastPlugin.java:14: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
                                 ^
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-2.2.11\android\src\main\java\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast\fluttertoast\FluttertoastPlugin.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
          Drawable shapeDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.toast_bg);
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable ContextCompat
  location: class FluttertoastPlugin
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 19s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Exception: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using an older version of cloud_firestore. Could you add your .yaml dependencies?

Comment: environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.6.6
  google_sign_in: ^3.2.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  fluttertoast: ^2.2.6




  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

Comment: You're using a very old version of firebase_auth. I didn't check rest. Update your dependencies by checking for the latest version on pub.dev

Comment: yes I updated but I have following error now 'FirebaseUser' is deprecated and shouldn't be used The method 'signInWithGoogle' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'.

Comment: Ya You need to user User instead of FirebaseUser.